# How to generate environment variable name dynamically and export it

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

I want to generate environment variable name dynamically and set the value to that variable. I wrote a shell script as below.

```
temp="$(date +%s)"
echo $temp
export ${temp} = "Test value"
echo "Pass variable ${temp}"
```

In the above code, generated timestamp should be the key and "Test value" is the value for that key.
This key and value have to export to the session.

How can I achieve this using shell script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `printf -v` to create variables dynamically, for example:

```
temp=somename
echo $temp
printf -v $temp "Test value"
echo $somename
```

This will output "Test value".

Note that `temp="$(date +%s)"` won't work, because the output of `$(date +%s)` is numeric, and variable names in Bash cannot start with a number. You would have to give it a non-numeric prefix, for example:

```
temp="t$(date +%s)"
```

To export the variable, you can simply do:

```
export $temp
```

Here's a complete example, with proof that the variable really gets exported in the environment:

```
temp=t$(date +%s)
echo $temp
printf -v $temp "Test value"
export $temp
sh -c "echo \$$temp"
```

Outputs for example:

```
t1486060416
Test value
```

Comment: @AlexanderMills I re-read it and I don't see what you mean. Which part is unclear to you?

Comment: I think indirect variables is a better answer? http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html

Comment: I guess it's called indirect references not indirect variables

Comment: @AlexanderMills Certainly, using indirect references would be possible too. Feel free to post your answer using that technique instead of `printf -v`.